# Unable to use a detailsview to insert data when it's inside a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-ui, web

I seem to be unable to use my asp detailsview to insert data into my database if I place it inside a [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default). However it works fine as long as I place it directly inside the page.

When I place it inside the dialog I can still fill out the information, but when I submit the SQL server complains about using NULL-values like so:

```
 Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Alias', table 'GSSNetDB.dbo.GSSNet_EndUsers'; column does not allow nulls
```

So seemingly the postback function can't read the information from the html form inside the dialog for some reason.

I create the dialog using this:

```
<div id="dialogEndUser" title="Create new user">
    <asp:DetailsView 
        ID="DetailsView_EndUsers"
        runat="server"
        Caption="Enter new user details"
        Visible="True"

        AutoGenerateInsertButton="True"
        AutoGenerateRows="False"

        DataKeyNames="Alias"
        DataSourceID="EndUserSource"
        DefaultMode="Insert">
        <Fields>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Alias" HeaderText="Alias" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Alias" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address*" SortExpression="Address" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name*" SortExpression="Name" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Device_Key" HeaderText="Device Key" SortExpression="Device_Key" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone_Number" HeaderText="Phone_Number" SortExpression="Phone_Number" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="E_mail" HeaderText="E-mail" SortExpression="E_mail" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
</div>
```

And the actual popup using:

```
$(function () {
  $("#dialogEndUser").dialog({
    height: 350,
    width: 300,
    position: "top",
    modal: false,
    autoOpen: false
  });
});
```

The datasource looks like the following:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="EndUserSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GSSNetDB %>"   
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Users] ([Alias], [Address], [Device_Key], [Name], [Phone_Number], [E_mail], [Description]) VALUES (@Alias, @Address, @Device_Key, @Name, @Phone_Number, @E_mail, @Description)">
  <InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Alias" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Device_Key" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Phone_Number" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="E_mail" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
  </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out or give any pointers on how to approach the problem. Maybe try using a different dialog system if someone has a recommendation?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I worked around it instead using a different dialog window instead where it works great. Still a strange problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that although you did set `dataKeyName="Alias"` there is no value for the parameter withing your insertCommand as you set this boundField to `ReadOnly="True"`.

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Users] (
           [Alias], [Address], [Device_Key], [Name], [Phone_Number], [E_mail], [Description]) 
    VALUES (@Alias, @Address, @Device_Key, @Name, @Phone_Number, @E_mail, @Description)"
```

Could you please verify that **@Alias** *got a value on inserting?* (for example: use Inserting Event of the SqlDataSource and debug/watch `e.Command.Parameters["@Alias"]`  .

On the other hand you wrote that it is **working fine** *if you place your detailsView outside the jQuery dialog* which makes me wondering?! *Am I missing something? Any comments/feedback are welcome!*

Comment: Alias does indeed not get a value upon insertion. Which leads me to believe that somehow jquery is messing with the postback function somehow. However I'm not quite sure how to resolve it. I also tested again to make sure, and it does indeed work when I use the control outside of the jquery dialog, which is weird. Oh and I tried removing the readonly property, and it is still acting the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jQuery creates its floating DIV elements outside of the FORM element and moves the DetailView table into these divs; so the values do not get included in postback. You can test this by creating a textbox `input(runat=server)` on the page outside of the form and observe that it will not return a value after postback.  You can see the div elements outside the form element by inspecting the page with your browser's developer tools while the dialog is visible.

I am not certain how I will fix this yet. My first idea would be to have hidden fields inside the form that have their values updated from the inputs in the DetailsView table using JavaScript before the dialog closes; though this would eliminate the usefulness of the `DetailsView` control.  It may be simpler than this though as I would hope there would be an easy way to tell jQuery to build its dialog divs inside the form element.  I will research the jQuery fix a little and post again if I find anything.